# Adding ad-hoc Wifi without breaking existing ethernet.. no bridge or routing

Tags: raspbian, wifi, buster

I have two Pi-4s, each with a unique static eth0 address; I use this connection for admin support.. They're running Buster.

I want the two Pi's to communicate to each other via Wifi and UDP. No router will be present. They must have known addresses so that #1 can broadcast to #2 using UDP; so, static IP on the Wifi side also.

All the ad-hoc examples seem to ignore existing networks - and attempting to set it up breaks the existing eth0 static IP setup in DHCP.

I could set one of the Pi's up as an access point, but I don't need bridging or routing.. I just want them to 'see' each other over the Wifi. The access point examples I find tend to include the other things, including dhcp ranges, bridging, etc that I don't need.

Can anyone suggest a simple means of getting the two Pi's communicating so that #1 can broadcast to #2 via WiFi, and continue to allow me access via ssh through the ethernet interface?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: "breaks the existing eth0 static IP setup in DHCP" "No router will be present" so where does DHCP come from? It should be possible to setup an ad-hoc wireless network independently of Ethernet. What have you tried that doesn't work? Frankly with 2 nodes ad-hoc makes no sense an Access Point would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to trying to set up the receiving device as an access point.

The problems I was having was that the SSID and passphrase I used were too short; there is an 8-character minimum.

Attempting to start hostapd would say it failed, and journalctl -xe would report `"failed to start advanced ieee 802.11 ap and ieee 802.1x/wpa/wpa2/eap authenticator"`.

Because I'm using fixed IP addresses for each device I was looking for the most simple configuration, and not using ip routing or bridging.

The configuration changes required to make this work follows:

Added two lines to /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

```
static ip_address=192.168.XX.YYY/24
```

(note that `XX.YYY` should be replaced with your choice)

Next, I added these two lines to /etc/dbsmasq.conf:

```
dhcp-range=192.168.XX.1,192.168.XX.20,255.255.255.0,24h
```

(Again, XX represents your choice, as should the range you choose)

Next, /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf reads like this:

```
interface=wlan0
country_code=US
driver=nl80211
ssid=MyGreatSSID
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=MyGreatPassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Where `MyGreatSSID` is a substitute for the one I use. No quotes around it in the file, btw.. and `MyGreatPassword` is the substitute (in this example) for our actual password.

Last item, point hostapd to the file, editing /etc/default/hostapd:

Update this line: `DAEMON_CONF=`
to this: `DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"`

There was an entry in /etc/rc.local to down the wlan0 interface that I changed it to bring it up; it was there from 'before', and I don't know if it comes that way by default or some previous project had left it there.

Reboot - and I was able to connect from Windows 10.